# Replacing text in button - radio Dialog

Tags: android

creating a radio button dialog.

I have found this tutorial which works great, however when the value is selected instead of a toast I want this to replace the text in the button.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(
                DialogInterface dialog, 
                int which) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    mContext, 
                    "Select "+choiceList[which], 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    )
                    .show();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
final String [] fruits = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fruits_array);
    builder.setItems(R.array.fruits_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            pickFruitButton.setText(fruits[which]);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thats what I want but I don't have an array defined in my xml, I've defined this as per the tutorial through the java so there is above my code:
final CharSequence[] choiceList =
                {"Coke", "Pepsi" , "Sprite" , "Seven Up" };

        int selected = -1; // does not select anything


        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(
                choiceList,
                selected,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

Comment: Sorry that works perfectly I just read it wrong - thank you so much for your help :)! Its much appreciated!